# Как загрузить фотографии в альбом сообщества через vk_api?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
x  = vk.photos.getUploadServer(album_id=279888888,group_id=207088888)
coll = {}
for i,v in enumerate(src):
    with open(rf"C:/Users/Idensas/Downloads/{v[-8:-4]}.{v[-3:]}",'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(v).content)
    coll[f'file{i+1}'] = open(rf"C:/Users/Idensas/Downloads/{v[-8:-4]}.{v[-3:]}",'rb')
riv=requests.post(x['upload_url'], files=coll).text
mda={'server':int(riv[10:16]),'photos_list':riv[32:(riv.find('aid')-3)],'hash':riv[riv.find('hash')+7:riv.find('gid')-3]}

vk.photos.save(album_id=279793394,group_id=207075487,server=mda['server'],photos_list=mda['photos_list'],hash=mda['hash'])
```

В src лежат просто ссылки, через них скачиваются на ПК фотки и уже потом это отправляется в вк. Однако выводит:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid
```

Не подскажите, пожалуйста, что я упускаю? Уже день ломаю голову над этим.

Вот так выглядит print(mda['photos_list'])

```
[{\"markers_restarted\":true,\"photo\":\"4993f89a8f:w\",\"sizes\":[],\"latitude\":0,\"longitude\":0,\"kid\":\"aebe218118d5f7324d0eeb7434848e0e\",\"sizes2\":[[\"s\",\"bd12e364c89d190e87d0374361398cc868616e0af77334eeacec1c2e\",\"4861637718117373304\",47,75],[\"m\",\"d4a671523634a27ef77a7325004cf703dc4b0cf3433915529845fcfd\",\"-3412362102944306800\",81,130],[\"x\",\"11308ce47e0d9b9b40cd6aeb95f1331b18d536aed98b5a89cdb5bc19\",\"-5295827408070577863\",377,604],[\"y\",\"d7e4f3f777a05a8b71b39824950bd784bdefe011b8733c930c161732\",\"1172340282644043135\",504,807],[\"z\",\"84badfe185ee3374d5c50bf242ead6433763eec531dd28bb7b6453ed\",\"8077752390548797106\",675,1080],[\"w\",\"64553d582bb52aba3b42b63fe78c6694626ee73540911bb29bd39d47\",\"671187300974608051\",750,1200],[\"o\",\"671b3328b43f21fc849d635629509d6c888af9d5b5546cb9595797b2\",\"1508296215877338269\",130,208],[\"p\",\"7c40da8e873d2369ad849b11ef40a481aec0d8b3897fe71eed2b711a\",\"-8748360126150935064\",200,320],[\"q\",\"3ebbf43315f220c8073cb815ad7692bb23a0e0d2a71e14037f057a6b\",\"-5980206978593975970\",320,512],[\"r\",\"ef1b0ea2abc53436646d86405a1cb4aebdd5c25a97f39e3b7196cdf9\",\"3834318667501292866\",510,816]],\"urls\":[],\"urls2\":[\"vRLjZMidGQ6H0DdDYTmMyGhhbgr3czTurOwcLg/eNUGH78BeEM.jpg\",\"1KZxUjY0on73enMlAEz3A9xLDPNDORVSmEX8_Q/kOn_ML_apNA.jpg\",\"ETCM5H4Nm5tAzWrrlfEzGxjVNq7Zi1qJzbW8GQ/OfEs5gdxgbY.jpg\",\"1-Tz93egWotxs5gklQvXhL3v4BG4czyTDBYXMg/fxXhlkb9RBA.jpg\",\"hLrf4YXuM3TVxQvyQurWQzdj7sUx3Si7e2RT7Q/sjY5XgDxGXA.jpg\",\"ZFU9WCu1Kro7QrY_54xmlGJu5zVAkRuym9OdRw/sz5YTEuJUAk.jpg\",\"ZxszKLQ_IfyEnWNWKVCdbIiK-dW1VGy5WVeXsg/nURvw2qL7hQ.jpg\",\"fEDajoc9I2mthJsR70Ckga7A2LOJf-ce7StxGg/6P2U6dCUl4Y.jpg\",\"Prv0MxXyIMgHPLgVrXaSuyOg4NKnHhQDfwV6aw/XhGY_W8JAq0.jpg\",\"7xsOoqvFNDZkbYZAWhy0rr3VwlqX8547cZbN-Q/Qk0QVIM8NjU.jpg\"]},{\"markers_restarted\":true,\"photo\":\"93ef1826a4:w\",\"sizes\":[],\"latitude\":0,\"longitude\":0,\"kid\":\"adb457295e2c7d24ed95224cb49a2e95\",\"sizes2\":[[\"s\",\"d379d05a3f2af365d344ef42e185d5a06c74ade5824057eee98a985d\",\"-5492900995225861729\",47,75],[\"m\",\"987fbccf9845a7a41b3f7133460e9d31b5fc78bbbcea24b1c7affe5d\",\"703897729234181843\",81,130],[\"x\",\"deefe82cf1fc495621bcdc5e12ce3600e25acc270722611ed0bf657d\",\"-5455163146476856969\",378,604],[\"y\",\"60592c4a4a3db540815c3992b56a9a5479c2d9a91a87e7c87b8285ce\",\"8749948879318429330\",505,807],[\"z\",\"3a3a84c8e74af71e725fc613ad135a488b0622804e008988d3ba6daf\",\"2935218699966515218\",676,1080],[\"w\",\"82902380af0220e093b84bb360975ea3e7eeffc691fa8a176dfcac59\",\"-5660318573129541507\",750,1199],[\"o\",\"120941aeea53a498a019f4a03d0920517ed846983029547f6ce6b952\",\"7421628813186150641\",130,208],[\"p\",\"dd510f21c10151c5a4eefa04002f4c0c4e3244996e2ed2e204b09d40\",\"-3191166370003843103\",200,320],[\"q\",\"b246dbedf23cd4649710dbb2522cfe977a1732a26a20141fd74d5d17\",\"1558539219156695395\",320,511],[\"r\",\"28a157b9c059940b3d20f8a3da6fe755dd4fd99886c082f4dcac7bed\",\"-7642916808343294321\",510,815]],\"urls\":[],\"urls2\":[\"03nQWj8q82XTRO9C4YXVoGx0reWCQFfu6YqYXQ/n0EswaVLxbM.jpg\",\"mH-8z5hFp6QbP3EzRg6dMbX8eLu86iSxx6_-XQ/0x41XUG_xAk.jpg\",\"3u_oLPH8SVYhvNxeEs42AOJazCcHImEe0L9lfQ/d9lxXgVeS7Q.jpg\",\"YFksSko9tUCBXDmStWqaVHnC2akah-fIe4KFzg/ki6agiUQbnk.jpg\",\"OjqEyOdK9x5yX8YTrRNaSIsGIoBOAImI07ptrw/EoiWLdv9uyg.jpg\",\"gpAjgK8CIOCTuEuzYJdeo-fu_8aR-ooXbfysWQ/fVgRVT-CcrE.jpg\",\"EglBrupTpJigGfSgPQkgUX7YRpgwKVR_bOa5Ug/8bDDiBXs_mY.jpg\",\"3VEPIcEBUcWk7voEAC9MDE4yRJluLtLiBLCdQA/4Ye_EBizttM.jpg\",\"skbb7fI81GSXENuyUiz-l3oXMqJqIBQf101dFw/Y3lZjikLoRU.jpg\",\"KKFXucBZlAs9IPij2m_nVd1P2ZiGwIL03Kx77Q/j-7VHqjn7pU.jpg\"]},{\"markers_restarted\":true,\"photo\":\"2ac81bdbcc:w\",\"sizes\":[],\"latitude\":0,\"longitude\":0,\"kid\":\"afa4173b5a6e5d6ecd04214eb4d00a86\",\"sizes2\":[[\"s\",\"30c545011ded6603af3547f517db7d62d36f94aecd7a5059d81f751c\",\"4452840616248881203\",47,75],[\"m\",\"2d4a871dde044d3a535a900502b7a46fa32604d8e00e8c05839a87b2\",\"4588800961491332086\",81,130],[\"x\",\"1623a54c527a87d481d16fa24f71ee4b9fd898ba720620ca5fd4d91c\",\"-5127611456135587807\",377,604],[\"y\",\"1ba6ddc441d0432443dfb4eda83870e922bca1dda91091cf40206374\",\"-7579311258535670230\",504,807],[\"z\",\"0f7466c125b60e14a58b59f1141895afb8bb0103a035b0e007d1fa87\",\"-1178926936353236341\",675,1080],[\"w\",\"b2c20bf757df10a41c1b3c72794e92a61af286ea3bfbc5675ae2942e\",\"8492379140086687169\",750,1200],[\"o\",\"06567e0c6124fa5c1fb60d197ab1c7c2359d8e859a59072ddf849e38\",\"6852168669005318026\",130,208],[\"p\",\"66abb7e7aec22974e31fee7729d976e2682422337d7cdfa5cdb3c2c5\",\"-740526423340655258\",200,320],[\"q\",\"374591ac9678c81967e38a7615c9860784b4c9fccf407293a56b30de\",\"6575858432109632907\",320,512],[\"r\",\"3567243a48d37ebe9b891ed326e8a8c5287f838b6ccea3ee7f569b29\",\"-7424984846530704253\",510,816]],\"urls\":[],\"urls2\":[\"MMVFAR3tZgOvNUf1F9t9YtNvlK7NelBZ2B91HA/MzDyxPKqyz0.jpg\",\"LUqHHd4ETTpTWpAFArekb6MmBNjgDowFg5qHsg/9mupdimyrj8.jpg\",\"FiOlTFJ6h9SB0W-iT3HuS5_YmLpyBiDKX9TZHA/IZjQQowQ17g.jpg\",\"G6bdxEHQQyRD37TtqDhw6SK8od2pEJHPQCBjdA/Ks7cOJHg0JY.jpg\",\"D3RmwSW2DhSli1nxFBiVr7i7AQOgNbDgB9H6hw/i5qGljKco-8.jpg\",\"ssIL91ffEKQcGzxyeU6Sphryhuo7-8VnWuKULg/weXNVtX92nU.jpg\",\"BlZ-DGEk-lwftg0ZerHHwjWdjoWaWQct34SeOA/iocfoRnLF18.jpg\",\"Zqu3567CKXTjH-53Kdl24mgkIjN9fN-lzbPCxQ/Zl39NSQfufU.jpg\",\"N0WRrJZ4yBln44p2FcmGB4S0yfzPQHKTpWsw3g/i90mU2ckQls.jpg\",\"NWckOkjTfr6biR7TJuioxSh_g4tszqPuf1abKQ/gwzhD58n9Zg.jpg\"]}]
```

Comment: Надо было распарсить `riv` как json-контент, а не пытаться выгрызать подстроки по индексам

Comment: Ой, сейчас исправлюсь, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, наконец-то у меня получилось! Хорошего вам дня)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и сказал andreymal, надо было всего лишь распарсить riv как json.

```
x = json.loads(riv)
```

И всё, теперь можно оттуда брать инфу для отправки в vk.photos.save